# Using a GPIO pin as a power source

Tags: stm32, gps

I have an STM32F2 (reference manual [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf)) which is connected to a [GPS receiver](http://www.avnet-embedded.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/Files/Wireless/Jupiter-F2_Datasheet.pdf) through 5 pins. One of these pins is a power supply pin for the GPS.

All pins on the micro-controller are GPIO pins that need to be configured. (E.g. configure as input, output, floating, open-drain, push-pull, etc.) The ARM reference manual does not discuss GPIO pins as power sources.

What GPIO configurations do I need to apply to a power supply pin?

Comment: Check the power consumption of the GPS receiver, and the source capability of the GPIO pins. It probably won't be enough.

Comment: If your load consumed only a bit more than what one GPIO pin is able to provide (with a usable voltage after the drop), and you were really really space constrained, you could tie N GPIO pins together, and drive them all equal, to sum their currents. I've done this for light loads, but a GPS receiver is not the case.

Comment: @Telaclavo, I've done this and it works, but be sure to check the microcontroller's maximum total current spec as well as the individual pin current spec.

Comment: @markrages Sure, I always check that.

Comment: STM32 GPIO can only source 3mA max, if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Note:
>
>   This answer was originally written before we knew anything about the receiver, like its 1.8V power supply. Telaclavo's answer is good. As a more general answer the PNP/MOSFET solution remains; you don't want to power parts of your circuit from a microcontroller's I/O pin.*

You don't want to do that! You'd configure the pin as output and make it high to provide power to the GPS receiver, but microcontrollers I/Os can only supply limited current, 25mA for the STM32F205xx (Section 6.2 page 72 of the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00237391.pdf)), which will be too low for powering your (and any other) GPS receiver (34 to 38 mA, as stated in the [datasheet](http://www.avnet-embedded.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/Files/Wireless/Jupiter-F2_Datasheet.pdf))

Use the I/O pin to drive a [PNP transistor](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC856_BC857_BC858.pdf) which will supply the required current.

[image]

Note that using a PNP inverses your logic: a logic low will turn the receiver on.

I would not use an NPN for this. In common emitter it would mean that the receiver's ground is a few hundred mV above ground, and a circuit should have one single ground which is the same for every component. In common collector you would lose too much of your 3.3V power supply.

**edit**
Wouter would use a MOSFET instead of a BJT, and that's a good alternative. Just make sure you choose a logic-level FET, which will give you enough current at a \$V_{GS}\$ of -3.3V. The Rohm [RZE002P02](http://www.rohm.com/products/databook/tr/pdf/rze002p02.pdf) is a suitable type. It will also have a lower voltage drop if your receiver needs less than about 200mA.

**edit 2** (re clabacchio's addition of a datasheet)
This device operates at 1.8V, the STM32 at 3.3V. You can use an [LDO with an enable input](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic5233.pdf) and control that from your microcontroller. No transistor needed. (Thanks for the suggestion, *markrages*.) You'll also need level shifters for the data.

Comment: I'd suggest a logic-level P MOSFET, but the principle is the same.

Comment: If you have an LDO, the PNP/P-channel transistor is built-in.  Just choose an LDO with an enable input and drive that with the micro.

Comment: Any particular reason why you suggest a PNP over an NPN?

Comment: @Saad - an NPN would let the receiver's ground float a few hundred mV above the controller's ground. You don't want that, ground should be ground. With the PNP we're losing these 200mV in the power supply, which doesn't do any harm.

Comment: This 200mV is dropped across CE junction of the PNP? If so, the datasheet states 300mV for V_CE(sat). But, why can't the load be connected from emitter to ground when using a NPN?

Comment: Yes, is there a reason why it needs to be common emitter?

Comment: @Saad - no, I could have suggested the common collector you mention. I don't think one solution is better or worse than the other. Just habit I guess.

Comment: @stevenvh Thanks. Just wanted to be sure - I'm just a newbie and I miss a lot of small things so I thought I had better ask if there is any difference. :)

Comment: if your load is too high ,then I suggest you to use a power scr with a simple pulldown feedback.

Comment: @Saad - come to think of it: in the common collector the output voltage at the emitter will be 0.7V lower than the base voltage, so you have a higher voltage drop, which also means higher dissipation in the transistor.

Comment: @Saad and Steven: with digital signals, the 300 mV do approximately the same harm (nothing) raising the ground level or lowering the supply level, so an NPN in common emitter configuration is also an option here (if all signals between the MCU and the GPS receiver are digital). With MOSFETs, the choice (between using PMOS in common source or NMOS in common source) would even be more indifferent. In fact, an NMOS would have a lower on resistance.

Comment: @Telaclavo - You can have multiple power supplies, but you have only one single ground in your system!

Comment: @stevenvh Not only I never said that my comment was valid for all cases, but I wrote "is also an option __here__", and emphasized twice on the digital nature of the signals. See Table 5 in the datasheet. Vil_max = 0.45 V. That means that 0.3 V would be interpreted as input low. For the high level, and going backwards, it all depends on the level shifters (which won't have any problem, either). // I do defend many things that I would not do (because they are not optimal), but not being optimal does not make them incorrect. // And I admit I enjoy seeing ppl confuse one thing with the other.

Comment: @Telaclavo - Yes, I understand your point, and I agree that the levels will be OK, but for me this is a matter of principle :-), you can't have one ground and another ground which is 200mV higher.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, now that I read the datasheet, it says clearly ([in Note 1 of Table 3](http://www.avnet-embedded.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/Files/Wireless/Jupiter-F2_Datasheet.pdf))

[image: Note 1 of Table 3]

So, you should not interrupt the power path to the GPS receiver, and instead do something like this:

[image: Schematic]

Note that, according to Table 6, the ON_OFF pin is 3.6 V tolerant. The GPS will be ON when that GPIO signal is high.